# Inflating same RelativeLayout multiple times to populate main LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-inflate

After searching here and though google for 1½ hour with no solutions I'll ask here. (Read though all the SO posts I could find, and tried the solutions but they didn't work or gave me an idea to what goes wrong)

I got a main LinearLayout that is empty and then an RelativeLayout in another xml file. What I want is to inflate the the RelativeLayout for each "setting" I'm adding. However when I try to do that only the first inflation works, the rest doesn't show up. I can't quite see what goes wrong otherwise than I suspect it's in issues with IDs.

I have tried to change the IDs for each time I inflate and add the layout, but that doesn't help. Can though debug confirm that the mainlayout get the relativelayouts as childs, and that their id's differ. But still no luck.

Hoping I can get a helping push in the right direction to understand what actually goes wrong here. :)

Activity code: (It's the BuildSeekBarView() that inflate and populate the Relativelayout

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SettingsDao settingsDao;
    private List<Settings> allSettings;
    private int lastChildId = 9000;
    private int lastSeekbarId = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        //get data from database.
        DaoSession daoSession = ((App) getApplication()).getDaoSession();
        settingsDao = daoSession.getSettingsDao();

        //get data
        allSettings = settingsDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(SettingsDao.Properties.Key).list();

        //change list to hashmap
        Map<String, Settings> map = new HashMap<String, Settings>();
        for(Settings item : allSettings) map.put(item.getKey(), item);

        //build all the views
        //Hardcode for different types. Need to edit code to support new types of sensors anyway
        /** Temperature **/
        int tempMax = Integer.parseInt(map.get(SETTING_TEMP_MAX).getValue());
        buildSeekBarView(tempMax, map.get(SETTING_TEMP_UPPER_BORDER), 0.2, getString(R.string.Settings_Temp_High_Zone_Border));
        buildSeekBarView(tempMax, map.get(SETTING_TEMP_LOWER_BORDER), 0.2, getString(R.string.Settings_Temp_Low_Zone_Border));

        /** Humidity **/
        int humiMax = Integer.parseInt(map.get(SETTING_HUMI_MAX).getValue());
        buildSeekBarView(humiMax, map.get(SETTING_HUMI_UPPER_BORDER), 1.0, getString(R.string.Settings_Humi_High_Zone_Border));
        buildSeekBarView(humiMax, map.get(SETTING_HUMI_LOWER_BORDER), 1.0, getString(R.string.Settings_Humi_Low_Zone_Border));

        /** Air Quality **/
        int airQMax = Integer.parseInt(map.get(SETTING_AIRQ_MAX).getValue());
        buildSeekBarView(airQMax, map.get(SETTING_AIRQ_UPPER_BORDER), 10.0, getString(R.string.Settings_AirQ_High_Zone_Border));
        buildSeekBarView(airQMax, map.get(SETTING_AIRQ_LOWER_BORDER), 10.0, getString(R.string.Settings_AirQ_Low_Zone_Border));

        //TODO at end add save btn and listener for that

    }


    public void buildSeekBarView(int max, Settings setting, final Double step_size, String title) {
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearContainer);

        //inflate xml layout and insert into main layout
        RelativeLayout settingView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_settings_layout, null);

        if (lastSeekbarId != 0) {
            //addrule
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastSeekbarId);

            settingView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        }

        settingView.setId(lastSeekbarId + 5);
        lastSeekbarId = settingView.getId();

        //Get Childs in created view
        SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) settingView.findViewById(R.id.settingSlider);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) settingView.findViewById(R.id.settingName);
        final TextView seekBarValueView = (TextView) settingView.findViewById(R.id.seekbarValueText);    

        titleView.setText(title);
        titleView.setTag(setting.getId()); //set tag = database ID for this setting

        double proportional = (1 / step_size); //Looses a bit in the high-end as it rounds down if that is the closest int. consider adding fixed amount more to pad the possible loss
        seekbar.setMax((int) ((int) max*proportional)); //multiply with proportional for resolution
        seekbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(setting.getValue()));

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    if (progress >= 0 && progress <= seekBar.getMax()) {

                        //Multiply with x to get away from ints and be able to set border in x intervals
                        String progressString = String.valueOf(progress * step_size);
                        seekBarValueView.setText(progressString); // the TextView Reference
                        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(progress);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        mainLayout.addView(settingView);
    }
}
```

RelativeLayout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_setting_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/settingSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingName"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekbarValueText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/settingSlider"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LinearLayout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

How the Activity looks when run:

[image]

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` is horizontal, so all the `View`s you're adding after the first get pushed out the side. Also, since the `settingView` is going into a `LinearLayout`, it should have `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, not `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Damn, you are absolutely right. don't even need the `layoutParams` after I changed the `LinearLayout` to vertical. Can't believe i missed that!    
If you want you can submit it as a answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Yeah, it's an easy thing to overlook the first few times. Anyhoo, this is a pretty common question here, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help :)